# SSH Address family not supported by protocol on git pull

Tags: git, ssh, web-hosting, ovh

Context : 
I have a homemade git repository on my 1&1 shared hosting. Which works perfectly when I push/pull from my Windows10 using Putty or gitBash. It works from my OVH VPS too.

But today I'm trying to git pull a project on the same 1&1 shared hosting from a OVH shared hosting where I'm ssh logged. 
When I :

```
git clone  <myuser>@<myhost>:git/<clientproject>.git
```

I have an error :

```
socket: Address family not supported by protocol
ssh: connect to host <myhost> port 22: Address family not supported by protocol
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

So I tried to pull a public git repo found on the internet, for example git clone https://git.drupal.org/project/drupal.git which works just fine.

I guess I have to update some ssh config on the OVH or 1&1 shared hosting but I do not know if it's possible on these host solutions or how do it.

I will appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect you have configured your system to *allow* IPv6 connections, but not to *support* IPv6 connections. See, e.g., https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-528455-start-0.html